# Hibernate model OneToOne do not share entire object?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, architecture, model

I am discovering Jpa and Hibernate and I have a question about repository and model (using spring).

I have an object "Structure" with some fields ( id and type for example ) and a lot of others objects related to a structure : for example an address.
I would like to get the address like this in the AddressRepository :

```
 Address findByStructureId(long structureId);
```

But the only way I found is to have also an object Structure in the object Address. I don't know if this is a problem or not according to memory because Structure is a big object with a lot of subobjects like address.

In Structure

```
@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "structure", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private Address address;
```

In Address

```
@GenericGenerator(name = "generator", strategy = "foreign", parameters = @Parameter(name = "property", value = "structure"))
@Id
@GeneratedValue(generator = "generator")
private long structureId;

@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn
@JsonIgnore
private Structure structure;
```

I have another problem with architecture.
I need to keep all the "sub objects" of structure by year but I don't know how to do it. 
For example, I would like the address of structure #1 for the year #2012.

Comment: Why did you tag your question with restful-architecture ? It seems not to be much related...

Comment: I have changed the tags.

Answer (score 0):

I'll try to answer and I see several ways to improve your code.

> I don't know if this is a problem or not according to memory because
>   Structure is a big object with a lot of subobjects like address.

It's not a problem, thanks to lazy-loading. If you load an address object, but never call the getStructure method (or the structure object internally) the structure object will never be loaded from the DB.

Now with your address class :

```
@GenericGenerator(name = "generator", strategy = "foreign", parameters = @Parameter(name = "property", value = "structure"))
@Id
@GeneratedValue(generator = "generator")
private long structureId;
```

Why do you have the `structureId` as a generated primary key ?

The proper way to do this would be to have an `id` field that would be you generated PK. And a separate `structureId` field that would be your FK pointing to the `structure` table. The `structureId` field normally would exist only in the DB but not as a field of your address class. It would only be used as the key in the relationship annotation.

Also I would recommend using `Long` objects instead of `long` primary datatypes as key.

The main reason is that an object can be `null`, and that is very useful when using JPA, in order to determine if an entity has been persisted already or is newly created. I guess a long would have a value of zero, and you could check that, but that seems less safe.

Also it's easier if you want to use java collections together with IDs. For example you can't use a `long` as a `Map` key but you can use a `Long` object.

Finally, regarding the dated sub-objects, that would probably require a different table and class structure.

For one, the relationship would become a many-to-one (the many side being the `address`) and the address (and other) objects would have a `year` field, or even better a `startDate` and an `endDate` fields (so that if the address didn't change, it is not duplicated). Or you could have a third table `year` and the address would point to it as well as to the structure. It all depends on your requirements.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and your advises. About the generated primary key, I followed this tutorial http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-one-to-one-relationship-example-annotation/. The structureId is the same as the id of the structure object I think.

Comment: About the lazy-loading, i am not sure to understand because when I get an address, in the hibernate logs, I have two select requests : one for address and one for the related structure. If I put "optional=false" beside "fetch = FetchType.LAZY" in the Address object, there is only the address request and I think this is better because I do not need the structure when I get the address.

Comment: About the primary key : I guess it is possible to use the same key in both entities. But then it must be generated only on the parent side (the structure) and you must set it manually on the child entity (the address) when you create it.

Answer (score 0):

Update.. :)
Here is a part of the architecture

AnnualStructure :

```
@Entity
public class AnnualStructure {

@Id
@GeneratedValue
private Long annualStructureId;

private Long structureId;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "year_id")
private FinancialYear yearInformations;

@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "annualStructure", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private StructureInfos structureInfos;
}
```

StructureInfos :

```
@Entity
public class StructureInfos {

@GenericGenerator(name = "generator", strategy = "foreign", parameters = @Parameter(name = "property", value = "annualStructure"))
@Id
@GeneratedValue(generator = "generator")
private Long annualStructureId;

@OneToOne(optional = false, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn
@JsonIgnore
private AnnualStructure annualStructure;    

@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "structureInfos", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private Coordonnees coordonnees;

@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "structureInfos", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private StructureJuridique infosJuridique;
}
```

Coordonnees:

```
@Entity
public class Coordonnees {

@GenericGenerator(name = "generator", strategy = "foreign", parameters = @Parameter(name = "property", value = "structureInfos"))
@Id
@GeneratedValue(generator = "generator")
private Long annualStructureId;

@OneToOne(optional = false, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn
@JsonIgnore
private StructureInfos structureInfos;

private String street;
private String city;
}
```

I wanted to be able to access each information (coordonnees for example) easily with the annual structure id without getting the entire object AnnualStructure.
What do you think ?

Comment: I have a question. I would like to set unique the pair structureId/yearInformations in the AnnualStructure object. Is it possible ?